# How can I successfully display a "splash" screen (JFrame/JPanel) that gives the user a message before closing after a certain delay?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, timer, actionlistener

I have tried thread.sleep which ends up lagging the appearance of the `JLabel` and then immediately closing the program, and I have tried implementing the solutions I've found to "similar" questions that involved Timers.

Is there any straightforward way to do this within this `actionPerformed` to display this JFrame for a few seconds, and then `System.exit(0)`?

My partner and I (this is for a school project we have kind of gone off the rails with) have both been "googling" excessively and cannot understand the variable context solutions we have found. We are both working with 3 weeks of Java programming experience.

Thank you in advance, I apologize for my lack of expertise in applying the possible solutions from analogous questions.

```
private class ExitButton implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        JFrame exitMenu = new JFrame();
        JPanel message = new JPanel();
        JLabel punk = new JLabel("You can keep all that corporate BS");
        punk.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.ITALIC, 16));
        exitMenu.setSize(300, 150);
        exitMenu.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        message.add(punk);
        message.setVisible(true);
        exitMenu.add(message);
        exitMenu.setVisible(true);

        // some kind of timer/delay for like... 3-5 seconds

        System.exit(0);

    }
```

I tried using:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimedExit {
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask exitApp = new TimerTask() {
public void run() {
System.exit(0);
}
};

public TimedExit() {
timer.schedule(exitApp, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+5*1000));
}

}
```

... from another question/answer. But it tells me I need to make a method (which this does?) after I call TimedExit().

@ Swing Timer, again, I am having a hard time implementing what I am finding online which is tailored to general cases (and end up using a confusing amount of jargon that assumes the user understands the relevance of the placeholders they represent - however, I do not understand). As lazy as this may make me, I was hoping someone could tell me some code that would fit within this particular section of my code and would simply allow this JFrame display the asinine sentence and then System.exit(0).

If it truly is something too complicated to answer or do concisely, I apologize for bringing it up, and thank all who have attempted to assist me.

```
int delay = 3000; //milliseconds
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
  System.exit(0);
}
};
new javax.swing.Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

The above code submitted by Jayfray solved my problem!

Comment: Use a Swing `Timer`. For better help, post a [mcve] of your attempt.

Comment: Boondoggle: please don't post code or key important information in comments. Instead edit your question. Note that @AndrewThompson suggested that you use a **Swing** Timer, not a java.util.Timer. Any decent Google search would have already told you this however. If you need further help, post a valid [mcve] with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 int delay = 3000; //milliseconds
 ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      System.exit(0);
    }
 };
 new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

after your call to `exitMenu.setVisible(true);`

Comment: I tried that... http://imgur.com/a/opfvC

I hover over my squigglies and it wants me to add a cast(), remove arguments to match Timer. Thank you for the suggestion, however.

Comment: try using `new javax.swing.Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();` instead of just `new Timer(...)`

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much! I knew there was a concise solution out there, I just couldn't find it.

Comment: My apologies, I did not know how to do that. I believe I have fixed it by toggling the check mark. I also up-voted it, but my points are too low to publicly reflect my opinion.